# I cannot assign my result of my api request to the view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, httprequest, clarifai

This is only a portion of my code. For some reason I can assign vm.print to my response, it does not show. However, when I console.log() the response, it appears in the console. Please help. I can assign vm.print to any string outside of the app.model.predict(){} function but when I assign it inside the function, it does not show up in the view , but only shows up in the console.

```
 <main class="app container" ng-controller="webcamController as vm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center">
            <ng-webcam config="vm.config"
                       on-error="vm.onError(err)"
                       on-load="vm.onLoad()"
                       on-live="vm.onLive()"
                       on-capture-progress="vm.onCaptureProgress(src, progress)"
                       on-capture-complete="vm.onCaptureComplete(src)"></ng-webcam>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p id="progress">Progress: {{vm.progress}}%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 buttons" ng-if="vm.showButtons">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-disabled="!vm.captureButtonEnable" ng-click="vm.capture()">Capture</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="vm.off()">Camera off</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="vm.on()">Camera On</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="result" class="row"></div>
    <!-- Displays analysis -->
    <!--<div ng-repeat="x in analysis">
    <h3>Example heading <span class="label label-default">{{x.name}}</span></h3>
    </div>-->
    <div class="text-center">{{vm.print}}</div>

</main>


<script>
   vm.test(src);

   vm.test = function(src) {


    //converts to string
    var uri = src.toString();
    //String manipulation
    uri = uri.slice(23, uri.length);

    var app = new Clarifai.App(
      'kS3D7ofjZQYiyr_7uET1IemaxIzmnmK3vbX4Vhwt',
      'lvhKWZx9bMY1L0OMVmo9bMr9A9_PyCRgmP2FGvEJ'
    );

    //This message will show up
    vm.print = "Default message";

    // predict the contents of an image by passing in a url
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.GENERAL_MODEL, {base64: uri}).then(
    function(response) {

    //str returns a string
    var str = response.request.response;
     //converting string to json
    var json = JSON.parse(str);
    //returns result
    console.log(json.outputs[0].data.concepts[0].name);
    //this does not show up in the view
    vm.print = json.outputs[0].data.concepts[0].name;
    },
      function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      vm.print = "Opps, something went wrong :(   " + err;
    }
    );

};


</script>
```

This is only a portion of my code. It will not run in the console. I just need to someone to look at the syntax who is more familiar with angularjs and the clarifai api. thanks.

Comment: Based on this code snippet, I'd say the issue is that your code is not running in the scope of the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library that you're using when you execute `Clarifai.App`, but I'm guessing it's not an Angular lib, so it probably just doesn't run the digest cycle automatically for you in the promise resolve (`.then()` callback)

You have to do it yourself. Try to inject thr `$scope` service, and run the `$scope.$apply()` method, like this:

```
app.controller('webcamController', function ($scope) {
    /* ... */
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.GENERAL_MODEL, {base64: uri}).then(
        function(response) {
            /* ... */
            vm.print = json.outputs[0].data.concepts[0].name;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
})
```